# List ALL posts by author on author archive

Tags: loop, author

I'm having trouble setting up an author archive. I've come up with a few different loops, but I can't seem to get them quite right. I just want it to list *all* posts by the *current author*.

This shows posts by the current author, but `only 10 posts` (my default number, I guess):

```
<ul>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

This one lists *all* post by *all* authors.

```
<?php global $post;
    $args = array('numberposts' => -1);
    $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li <?php post_class($custom_classes) ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

This doesn't seem that hard. I'm probably missing something obvious. It seems like I need to get the author into a variable and pass it, but I thought that was assumed on the author archive. My attempts to do that just haven't worked.

Answer (score 1):

your `get_posts` overrides the normal `query_posts` query. For this to work properly you should use `query_posts` and merge in your numberposts setting with the original query, like so:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

Then you'll no longer need a custom loop either, you could just use a normal loop.

Comment: [According to the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), `'numberposts' and 'posts_per_page' can be used interchangeably.` In practice however, for me, `numberposts` didn't work while `posts_per_page` did.